# Rails cache not updating properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I am using the cache-digests gem and following the instructions as per the Railscast, it creates and reads from a cache as you would expect, but the cache does not seem to be updating properly in relation to an associated record.

When moving a listing from one category to another, the `category.live_entries` count stays the same for the category I move it **from**, but goes up for the one I move it to.

So it sounds like I need a `touch: all` type method so it touches the one I am moving it from as well as the one it is moving to?

_category.html.erb

```
<% cache category do %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to category.name, category %>
    <% if category.live_entries > 0 %>
        (<%= category.live_entries %>)
    <% end %>
      - <%= category.desc %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings

  def live_entries
    listings.where(verified: true).count
  end
end
```

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Guess I could create a before_update callback to touch the old category - but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok just adding this as an answer - but if anyone has a better solution please feel free to share.

I just added an after_update to touch the old category:

```
  def touch_old_category(listing)
    cat = listing.category_id_was
    Category.find(cat).touch if cat
  end
```